# java ftp freezes at opening binary mode data connection for file list

Tags: ftp

I have written a java class to retrieve the file from ftp location and then saving it to a windows server. It just got hang while creating data connection :

it freezes at this line :

INFO: 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for file list

Any idea what may have caused this? I already have a batch job running for the same ftp which copies files using ASCII mode data connection and it works fine.

Please help!

Comment: did it happen repeteadly? can you show us the code you are running?